# How to sum column varchar values in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to sum same values like this in col1 or col2 instead of integrations I want to sum of how much integrations in column I have ex. (2)

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               Col1                |    Col2    | 
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| Integrations                      | 01-2       |    
| Integrations                      | 01-2       |       
| Missions                          | 05-7       | 
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: What is the desired result, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query gives you distinct results:

```
select Col1, count(distinct Col2)
from table
group by Col1
```

So number of `Integrations` will be `1`.

If you want to have a total number of `Integrations`, you should use this query:

```
select Col1, count(Col2)
from table
group by Col1
```

Which gives you the number of `Integrations` of `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - with `distinct count` and `group by`

```
select col1,count(distinct col2)
from tablename
group by col1
```